# Strapi V4 - How to remove data and attributes fields from GraphQL queries in playground?

Tags: graphql, strapi

How to remove data and attributes fields from GraphQL queries with Strapi v4.8.2 in playground?

**ExampleDe:**

before:

```
query queryGames($limit: Int!, $start: Int) {
 games(pagination: { limit: $limit, start: $start }) {
  data {
   attributes {
    ...campos
   }
  }
 }
}
```

after:

```
query queryGames($limit: Int!, $start: Int) {
 games(pagination: { limit: $limit, start: $start }) {
  ...campos
 }
}
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I have so many data and attributes in several nested fields, I waste a lot of time in my code trying to access the right properties.